# LsaEnumerateAccountRights always returns "File not found"

Tags: security, winapi

I'm calling the Advapi32.dll LsaEnumerateAccountRights function having a policy handle from LsaOpenPolicy and an account SID from LookupAccountName.

However, try as I might, I'm always getting back 0xC0000034 which after translation by LsaNtStatusToWinError gives me "The file referenced cannot be found."

Which isn't a whole lot of good.  My code handles this and goes on to grant the account SID the SeServiceLogonRight using LsaAddAccountRights, so I know that the policy handle and the account SID are fine as that would bomb out if something was wrong with one of those.

The end result is that the account does have the right it needs so overall the code works.

However, I'm using this within an MSI custom action, the Install checks to see if the account has the right and if it doesn't (or it fails as above) it grants the right and remembers it has done it in the install state.  If a rollback happens and it added the right it then removes it.  We never remove in an uninstall as other applications may have been installed using the same domain account that the services we run use.

So the problem is when an MSI performs a rollback - it will always remove the right as it always thinks it has added it.  So checking the rights using LsaEnumerateAccountRights is used for this - but I just can't get it to work.

Any idea - please note that I'm using c# with DllImport attribute to expose the Win32 functions, and I'm not the worlds best Win32 programmer having been Unix before C#!

Answer (score 11):

I have been struggling with this, too, but have just cracked it...

Retrospectively, I now see there was a clue in the msdn documentation:
"The accounts returned by this function hold the specified privilege directly through the user account, not as part of membership to a group."

See: [link text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms721792%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Get the policy handle from LsaOpenPolicy() and an account SID from LookupAccountName() exactly as you said.

If the username you entered was the name of a group ("Users", "Administrators", etc) then LsaEnumerateAccountRights() works fine and enumerates all the rights for the group.

If you call it on a username whose rights derive solely from the groups of which it is a member, then it returns 0xc0000034 (= Windows error 2 - The system cannot find the "file" specified), meaning (we now realise) "cannot find any individually assigned additional rights". It seems that the Windows Error 2 translation is a catch-all for "what you were looking for has not been found".

Now...
If you have ntrights.exe, run it... for example:

ntrights +r SeNetworkLogonRight -u MyUserName

Then, LsaEnumerateAccountRights() works fine, returns without error and enumerates a single right, "SeNetworkLogonRight".

Answer (score 1):

I have recently run up against this same problem.  In my testing with this issue it appears that the LookupAccountName call returns a security principal rather than the full SID.  The actual failure seems to be that the section within the SID where the user rights would be is either not there or shortened to only the logon right.

Performing a LookupAccountName call on the current logged in user and then trying to LsaEnumerateAccountRights against that SID results in only the user logon right.  Even though clearly, there are many other rights attached.  Trying to retrieve any other users, other than the logged on user, successfully returns a SID.  However, that SID will not have any user rights in it.

I have tested this on no domain workgroup systems and member systems of domains both as admin and regular users.  The LookupAccountName call when successful, always results a SID that does not contain the full set of user rights.

I can only assume that if a complete SID could be obtained from the Security Database, then the LookupAccountName would properly iterate the rights.

Answer (score 0):

I too have the exact same problem. Somebody suggested I get the SID via WMI with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM Win32_Account WHERE domain = 'ntdomain' AND name = 'username'
```

I tried it, using `ConvertStringSidToSid()` to get the magic blob `LsaEnumerateAccountRights()` expects and... same error. "The system cannot find the file specified."

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same problem, it is because you dont assign spefic privledge to the user, so the user priveldge is empty, if you add one to it, it wont fail.

Call the same function with a group you can see everything working correctly.