# Check if user can start service

Tags: c#, service, policy, advapi32

I just searched a lot in the web but I could not found any help. I have a own windows service and now it should be possible to configure it from my main software.

I have no problems with installing, starting, stopping, changing and uninstalling it. I can also install the service with other user credentials.

But there's the problem. Before installing the service ("cmd" call ***sc create SERVICENAME [...]***) I want to check if the user with the entered credentials can start services or not. So I need to check if he is entered at the local "Log On as a Service" security policy. I do **not** want to change the policy, I only want to check if he is allowed to do this.

Is it possible to do this check simply in C#?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/21238484/5243037

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the "Log On as a Service" is a login type of LOGON32_LOGON_SERVICE which you can get from Advapi32.dll. The first thing I found (that may be most helpful) is the [LogonUser function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378184(VS.85).aspx) that attempts to log on as the user, so it may be able to be used as a detection if logging on as LOGON32_LOGON_SERVICE for your user fails or succeeds.

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee391633(v=vs.85).aspx) is a full list of core server functions. Some listed look promising but may needs some trial-and-error such as AuditQuerySystemPolicy and such. Best of luck!

Comment: I found a solution based on your answer, thanks for that.

The code I used is following:
`IntPtr hToken;
if (LogonUser(userDomainAndName[1], userDomainAndName[0], ServiceUserPassword, (int) LogonType.LOGON32_LOGON_SERVICE, (int) LogonProvider.LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, out hToken))
{
    // Code executing when succeed
    return;
}

// Code executing when failed
`